# Как правильно собирать проект на Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular2, webpack

Более двух лет я писал приложения на Angular 1 - 1.5 и использовал для собрки gulp. Сейчас я решил изучить Angular 2 и распространенный сегодня webpack. В процессе изучения узнал о cli для генерации приложений на Angular 2 и автоматизации создания компонентов, сервисов и т. д. Мне показалось это безумно удобным, но в то же время появилось два вопроса.

1. Означает ли использование cli, что мне не нужен ни gulp, ни webpack? Или есть смысл каким-то образом комбинировать эти инструменты? Если да, то как это делаете вы?
2. Допустим, я сгенерировал каркас приложения при помощи cli, создал какие-то компоненты, написал некоторое кол-во кода, и тут я понимаю, что хочу использовать другой препроцессор css, переименовать ряд компонентов и директив, создать новые модули и таким образом изменить файловую структуру проекта. Не станет ли это проблемой? И смогу ли я после этого продолжать использовать cli?

PS: Я понимаю, что cli работает на основе webpack, поэтому странно говорить, что использовать cli, значит отказаться от webpack. Но где искать конфигурационный файл webpack? Что, если я хочу автоматизировать заливку файлов по ftp, компиляцию jade или делать что-то еще, чего нет по умолчанию в cli?

Answer (score 2):

**По первому вопросу:**
Если вы создали каркас проекта при помощи `cli`, то использовать `gulp` и `webpack` уже не нужно. Порядок сборки и развёртывания таков:

1. Переходим в корневой каталог проекта
2. `npm install` - устанавливаем пакеты
3. `ng build --prod --aot` - собираем проект
4. В папке `/dist` корневого каталога будет лежать собранный проект.
5. При желании миницифицируем полученные файлы
6. Заливаем содержимое папки `/dist` на веб-сервер
7. Вуаля

**По второму вопросу:**
Для того, чтобы вытащить `webpack.config`, в корневом каталоге проекта, сгенерированного при помощи `cli`, выполните:

`ng eject`

В результате в консоли выведется сообщение о том, что извлечение проведено успешно, и что теперь для запуска проекта нужно использовать `npm run build... etc` а в корневом каталоге получите сгенерированный `webpack.config`, который можете конфигурировать как вам угодно. Следует отметить, что `ng serve` и прочие подобные команды использовать уже не сможете, а после извлечения в `package.json` добавится ряд новых пакетов, следовательно, перед запуском приложения после проведения извлечения, необходимо будет запустить `npm install`.
Следовательно, алгоритм таков:

1. Переходим в корневой каталог проекта
2. `ng eject`
3. Проверяем наличие `webpack.config`
4. Вносим необходимые изменения
5. `npm install`
6. `npm run build`
7. Вуаля :)